# how to configure linked resources in Netbeans the way it is done in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

how to configure linked resources in Netbeans the way it is done in [eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm)